# For MVC Array - Polygons - which is the best way to go?

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I need to go about building 2,800 polygons (using MVC Array) for a google maps (v3) and displaying some attribute information. There seems to me that there are two ways to do this:

1) just load an array of 15,000+ points from a MySQL db file. I am planning on generating these points using a vertices command in a GIS platform. All vertice points that are vertices of a common building polygon will share the same identifier (i.e. building id). I will generate the lat/longs of each of these points in the WGS84 coordinate system (i.e. EPSG 4326) http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326.

OR

2) Parse a MySQL Geometry file (which comes in the Blob format) into a readable set of coordinates for google maps to read. I am still fuzzy on how to do this....(especially dealing with Blob)...but I suspect I need to load the file in the WGS84 coordinate system and start from there. Also, need to load the dbf file (in order to call the attributes) and correspond this with the building id.

My questions are:

- Of option 1 & 2 what would be the best course of action to take for a low-experience programmer and the volume of data (i.e. 2000 polygons, which breakdown into 15000 points)?
- IS WGS 84 (EPSG 4326) what I need my polygon coordinates to be in??? I've found a lot of confusion on this (some sites suggest WGS 84 - Mercator, EPSG 3857). This is a rather critical processing step to know...so I really hope for some guidance if possible.

Thanks!!!